# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '_msgid'

Tags: node-red

I'm trying my hand on node-red...

[image]

I do this web query https://api.forecast.io/forecast/

This is the given output:

```
{"latitude":-25.74486,"longitude":28.18783,"timezone":"Africa/Johannesburg","offset":2,"currently":
{"time":1462871342,"summary":"Foggy","icon":"fog","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,
"temperature":18.08,"apparentTemperature":18.08,
"dewPoint":9.3,"humidity":0.57,"windSpeed":3.75,"windBearing":351,"visibility":2.78,
"cloudCover":0.23,"pressure":1024.87,"ozone":252.43}}
```

which seems correct.

The code in Parse Weather is

```
  //parse forecast.io message

 var weather = JSON.parse(msg.payload);

 return weather.currently.temperature;
```

The error I get is:

> *TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '_msgid' of 19.49*

The value seems ok.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any property named '_msgid' in your JSON. Can you also show JS code if you have any?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in your Parse Weather function. You are returning a int (18.08), Function nodes need to return a msg object.

Try something like this:

```
var weather = JSON.parse(msg.payload);
msg.payload = weather.currently.temperature;

return msg;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @NicovdDussen if this answer helped, you should mark it as accepted.  I've noticed this code block is the same that you posted in your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Found the dummy error.

Changed the function code to:

```
//parse forecast.io message

 var weather = JSON.parse(msg.payload);
 msg.payload = weather.currently.temperature;
 return msg;
```

All working now as expected :)